# Use of Trim () but there is only a blank space

Tags: java

```
        System.out.print("What is the name of the dog?> ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        if (name.equals(null) || name.trim().equals("")) {
        System.out.print("Error: Name can not be empty.");

        System.out.print(What breed is " + name + " ?>");
        String breed = scanner.nextLine();
```

My problem is that I want the question to repeat if no name is entered and repeat until a name is enteres, but it goes straight to next question(about breed). How do I solve it?

Comment: This is not how you check for `null`, it will throw `NullPointerException`. Use `name == null`.

Comment: Use a `do while` loop in the first statement

Comment: put the code inside a loop and exit when you have the values.

Comment: if (name.trim().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Error:Name can not be empty.");

Comment: How do I put a while and do loop in the first statement, I am a beginner at coding..

Comment: @Bea, search for loops in your textbook, there's a comprehensive explanation on those.

Comment: you are missing **"** after **print(** in **System.out.print(What breed is " + name + " ?>");** too

Answer (score 1):

You can place the line of code you want to repeat inside a loop until the input is valid. Also for checking if the variable is null use the == operator.

```java
    System.out.print("What is the name of the dog?> ");
    boolean flag = false;
    String name = null;
    do {
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        if (name == null || name.trim().equals(""))
            System.out.print("Error: Name can not be empty.");
        else flag = true;
    } while (!flag);

    System.out.print(What breed is " + name + " ?>");
    String breed = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid the time has come to learn about `functions` now. So, here use function like `getNonEmptyInput(Scanner scanner)` for each input. Also note that `null` check is *intensionally* *escaped* as `System.in` can never return a null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is the name of the dog?> ");
    String name = getNonEmptyInput(scanner);
    //do something with name
    System.out.print("What breed is " + name + " ?>");
    String breed = getNonEmptyInput(scanner);
    //do something with breed
}

private static String getNonEmptyInput(Scanner scanner) {
    String input;
    while (true) {
        input = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if(input.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Error: Input can not be empty.");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks! but sorry I don't think I still got it right. I **continue** if name is null or empty, won't that do it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks again for correcting me, I guess since he was asking about **"name"** and mentioned **"but it goes straight to next question(about breed)"** I assumed that he wan't the solution for that alone.

Comment: @RealSkeptic have update the answer, please check it out.